# Magento 2: How to create a downloadable product programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, downloadable

I try to create a import job but I do not know how to create a downloadable product programmatically.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html

I readed this site but I have no idea how to do that. How can I insert the download link to the product ? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should work.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$link_repository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Downloadable\Api\LinkRepositoryInterface');
$link_interface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface');
$link_interface->setTitle('first downloable product');
$link_interface->setPrice(9);
$link_interface->setNumberOFDownloads(10);
$link_interface->setIsShareable(1);
$link_interface->setLinkType('url');
$link_interface->setLinkUrl('http://www.example.com');
$link_interface->setSampleType('url');
$link_interface->setSampleUrl('http://example.com');
$link_interface->setIsUnlimited(0);
$link_interface->setSortOrder(0);
$link_repository->save('your_product_sku', $link_interface); 


// To add data under sample section:
$sample_repository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Downloadable\Api\SampleRepositoryInterface');
$sample_interface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\SampleInterface');
$sample_interface->setTitle('first downloable product');
$sample_interface->setSampleType('url');
$sample_interface->setSampleUrl('http://www.example.com/download/file.zip');
$sample_interface->setSortOrder(0);
$sample_repository->save('your_product_sku', $sample_interface);
```

> Note: Do not use objectManager directly. Use dependency injection.

Comment: I have to use code but give me an error like "The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again" any solution for this error.